# Is Settings.Bundle initialised automatically now?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

I have implemented settings for my app using settings.bundle and my app has been around for 2 years now. I have some settings that are set from within the App rather than from IOS Settings App. My issue before was that if the user did not initialise the settings by first going to the IOS Settings App then the settings set from in-app would not be recognised.

Now I've just been making some updates and doing my usual thorough testing and I notice that without ever navigating to the Settings App my settings that are set within my own app ARE now being recognised. Now I think I missed an important update. Did Apple change something with the way that settings.bundle, Settings App and in-app settings work?

(The only thing that I can think of is that I changed my IOS version for my target from IOS 5.1 to IOS 6.0... Could this be why my apps in-app settings just work seamlessly now?)